# Load an X509Certificate from PFX with both PEM Passphrase and Export Password

Tags: c#, openssl, x509certificate

I have generated a Key Pair using OpenSSL like this and specified **Password1**

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout MyApp.key -out MyApp.crt -sha256 -days 365 -passout pass:Password1
```

Then I generate PFX file as below, and specified **Password2** for export

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out MyApp.pfx -inkey MyApp.key -in MyApp.crt -password pass:Password2
```

When I load X509Certificate2, I just supply the Export Password for PFX. And I can still read the PrivateKey. What is the use of the "Password1", that I used initially to create Key Pair. Where do I specify that?

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Path\To\MyApp.pfx", "Password2", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Password1` would have been/is required to read the `MyApp.key` file to build the PFX.  Once it was read into the PFX the contents were re-encrypted with `Password2`.